# jquery off() using that object in chain

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using `off()`, and I'm not sure why this isn't working. I am not sure if this is this trying to `removeClass()` from `document` or `#pager-next`?

```
$(document).off('click', '#pager-next').removeClass('disabled');
```

I would like it to remove the class from `#pager-next` instead of `document`.

This however works:

```
$('#pager-next').removeClass('disabled');
```

But then I don't get the functionality of `off`

Comment: Why are you using `off()`? Seems like you want `on()`. Should work as-is in that case.

Comment: Why aren't you just doing `$('#pager-next').off("click").removeClass('disabled');` then?

Comment: Because I want to remove the click event. This is within an `if` statement that I left out

Comment: Your action flow isn't clear. Please describe it better.

Answer (score 0):

You should just not use the document element here, and apply your `off` directly to the element:

```
 $('#pager-next').off("click").removeClass('disabled');
```

If you want to retain the original event delegate, you will have to do it as shown on the jQuery docs and reference the function by name, otherwise all handlers will be removed:

```
function happensOn(){ alert("Stuff happens"); }
$('#pager-next').on("click", happensOn);
$('#pager-next').off("click", happensOn);
```

Have a look here: http://api.jquery.com/off/ (they have an implemented snippet at the bottom that shows how this works).

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what `off` does, it removes any delegated and set events for this item. Updated my post.

Comment: that just removes the javascript right? the `on()` just adds a `e.preventDefault()`, so when all requirements are complete we want to remove the `e.preventDefault()` with `off()`

Comment: `off()` also removes the default behaviour for a link if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a `find()` after the `off()` does the trick.

```
$(document).off('click', '#pager-next')
    .find("#pager-next").removeClass('disabled');
```